# How to convert user-defined struct to variant in c++?

Tags: c++, struct, com, variant

I have a `struct` in native c++, which should be passed to a COM object; both share same header file and hence there is no difference in struct definition between the COM object and my code. The COM method expects a pointer to `struct` as parameter. I am able to pass types like int, float, string, etc as parameters to COM by converting them to variant like `variant_t vtArg(myIntValue)`.

How do I convert `struct` to variant?

The signature of the COM method is like this:

```
bool ComMethod(HANDLE *myHandle, MyStruct *myStruct)
```

This is how I construct arguments for the COM method:

```
SAFEARRAY *pMethodArgs = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 2);
LONG index = 0;    
SafeArrayPutElement(pMethodArgs, &index, &myHandle);
index = 1;
SafeArrayPutElement(pMethodArgs, &index, &myStruct);
```

Comment: Sounds like you have native C++ on both side of the COM call... why use COM at all?

Comment: There are several things involved at application level. So, it is a COM call.

Comment: There is the `PVOID byref;` member, you can use that. But it will more than likely then be incompatible with the remaining non-C and non-C++ code in the COM application. The best may be to go all the way and wrap the struct up in another COM object...

Comment: @Niall: I tried this code to create the variant for the struct pointer, but unsuccessful. Please correct if I am making something wrong.

variant_t temp;
temp.vt = VT_PTR;
temp.byref = myStruct;

Comment: Try `temp.byref = &myStruct` -> `PVOID` is a `void*`. Once on the other side of the COM boundary make a copy of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried multiple ways and found that it is not possible to send `MyStruct` as parameter. I made the COM method return an instance of `MyStruct` and tried to reverse-engineer the return value in C++, but unfortunately nothing was received at C++.

The solution is to create a `SAFEARRAY` of `VARIANT` with individual members of the structure, or to pass the individual members as separate parameters.